# Encoding strings and ints for a RPC

Tags: c, function, rpc

I need to do a RPC. I'm trying to encode the length of a function name followed by the name of the function.

```
Function name: say_hello
Function name length: 9
Encoded array: [9, 's', 'a', 'y', ..., 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

So far:

```
unsigned char* encode_int(unsigned char *buffer, int value) {
  buffer[0] = value >> 24;
  buffer[1] = value >> 16;
  buffer[2] = value >> 8;
  buffer[3] = value;
  return buffer + 4;
}

char* function_name = "say_hello";
char* buffer[256];
buffer = encode_int(&buffer, strlen(function_name));
strcpy(buffer, function, strlen(function_name));
puts(buffer);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @atuos I can't get it to work, can you provide an example on how to do it properly? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that it's not working? Do you expect puts() to print '9say_hello'?

Comment: It looks like you've got a couple of issues, you shouldn't be using unsigned char in your function definition of Encode_int. Also when you call it you use &buffer rather than the correct buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of problems with your code. I won't just give you a working solution but will point out the problems. The first thing is that the code obviously doesn't compile. You are passing an undefined variable `function` to strcpy and give too many arguments to `strcpy`. I'll assume you've just transcribed the program incorrectly. But even if you fix that you will get a few compiler warnings which, if heeded, would identify most of your problems.

1. You are passing the address of `buffer` rather than the `buffer` itself to `encode_int`.
2. You declare `buffer` as an array of char **pointers**. Looks like what you really want is an array of `char`.
3. You encode an int into the start of the buffer. And then you try to print it as a string (via `puts`). That's not going to work and will result in no output (as you have probably found). Because the int will have a 0 value in the first byte (as you have encoded it). This is a null terminator for a string and hence the blank output.

EDIT: Correction to point 3. You've actually incremented `buffer` by 4 (if everyting else was fixed). So the `puts` will only show the function name (again, if everything else was fixed). And you've effectively lost the function name length.

Answer (score 0):

Put words into  buffer like this

```
int len;
len=Strlen(word);
memcpy(buffer,&len,sizeof(Int));
strncpy (&buffer[sizeof (int)],word,len);
```

Change the puts line to read

```
printf("%d %s\n",buffer,&buffer[sizeof (int)]);
```